# In D3 how to enable zooming only for particular path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a `d3` `geomap`. In that i enabled `zooming` feature by using `d3.behaviour.zoom()`.

Actually, `zooming` part is working fine.But my problem is i need to zoom only background layer.

I mean i  created a `world map`. In that over the each country i created a `circle`. So while zooming i need to increase the world map size not that `circle`. I need to show same size of `circle` always.

Please help me to solve this .Also, i added `fiddle` link below.Kindly take a look and help me.

Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/39/

Comment: Can you scale the circles inversely when the geomap is being scaled?

Comment: HI @VivekTodi.Thanks for suggestion.Can you please tell me how to scale inversely for this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/43/ . Because in this case my circle radius are dynamic.

Comment: I don't know the syntax and classes used in D3, but the logic would be fairly simple. 

You'd have to handle both the cases of zoom in and zoom out. In both of these, you should inversely scale the current radius of the circle with a factor in the answer below the scale factor is defined as `6/d3.event.scale` in the new scenario for zoom in it should be `r/d3.event.scale` where `r` is a `variable` containing the value of the radius of the circle.

And similarly in case of zoom out it should be `r*d3.event.scale`

Comment: ok @VivekTodi.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zoom behaviour does what you tell it to. In your fiddle:

```
function zoom() {
          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }
```

Notice that scaling and translation is performed over the whole `svg`. You need to define another variable that has `.countries` without `.dots` and perform the zoom only on `.countries`

First, apply the zoom only on the `<g>` that contain `.countries`

```
     var countries = svg.append("g") //apply zoom here.
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8])
        .on("zoom", zoom))
       .selectAll(".countries")
              .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
              .enter()
```

Then, in `zoom` function, scale and translate only the selected elements `this`

```
    function zoom() {
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/40/)

## Note:

Disabling the zoom behaviour from the circles will also disable panning, which means that the user can slide the map from under the circles. You need to handle this as well.

=============

Another solution is to reverse scale the circles sizes in the zoom function, as mentioned in the comment.

```
    function zoom() {
      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        svg.selectAll("circle").attr("r", 6/d3.event.scale);
    }
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/41/) for it.

## If circle sizes are variable:

You can store the "true radius" is a separate attribute and replace `6/d3.event.scale` by `trueR/d3.event.scale`

Here are the 2 updates in your fiddle.

```
//Store the original raduis is a "trueR" attributes
svg.selectAll(".dots")
        .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
      .attr("r",function(d,i){
          radius = Math.random()*20;
          return radius;
          
      })
      .attr("trueR", function(d){ return d3.select(this).attr("r")})
        .attr("fill","black")
        .attr("transform",function(d){                 
             var p = projection(d3.geo.centroid(d));
             return "translate("+p+")";
         });


//Use "trueR" in the zoom() function
    function zoom() {
      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        svg.selectAll("circle").attr("r", function(d){
              return (d3.select(this).attr("trueR"))/d3.event.scale;
        });
    }
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sam0kqvx/45/)

Comment: HI @ahmohamed. Thanks for your answer.I have one doubt for your second solution. You selected all circle and divide the radius with scale value.(svg.selectAll("circle").attr("r", 6/d3.event.scale);). If all circle radius are same means it will work.If suppose my Circle radius will be dynamic mean how to do ? Because every circle will have different radius.